# HDFS Sink with Flume Interceptor Morphline

Tags: flume

I am trying to read a syslog with Flume, splitting into parts using Morphline and writting the result with delimiter ',' into HDFS, but I don't know how to redirect the output of 'grok' into the sink.

Thanks!!

This is my morphline file:

morphlines : [
  {
    id : morphline1

```
commands : [
  {               
    readLine {
      charset : UTF-8
    }
  }

  {
    grok {
      dictionaryFiles : [/grok-dictionaries]
      expressions : {
        message : """<%{POSINT:priority}>%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:hostname} %{DATA:program}(?:\[%{POSINT:pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:msg}"""
      }
    }
  }

]
```

}
]

Answer (score 0):

Solved! This is the solution:

{ 
       java 
       { 
          code: """record.replaceValues("_attachment_body",   record.getFirstValue("_attachment_body").toString().getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
          return child.process(record);""" 
        } 
    }